Determining base class signatures for subclasses of a Pydantic BaseModel
TL;DR: Is there a way to:

have a custom initializer on a sub-subclass of a pydantic.BaseModel,
that shows a full and complete signature in Pylance,
without manually copying all the field names into every subclass constructor?

Simplified
Let's say I have this setup:
from pydantic import BaseModel

class NumberWithMetadata(BaseModel):
    value: float | int
    source: str

class FloatWM(NumberWithMetadata):
    value: float

Good so far. In VS Code when I type FloatWM( Pylance via IntelliSense shows me the full and correct signature, limited to floats only:
(*, value: float, source: str) -> FloatWM
However, I want my subclass to perform custom logic during initialization, so I need an initializer. I don't want the child class to have to know the details of the fields in the base class, so I **kwargs it:
class FloatWM(NumberWithMetadata):
    value: float

    def __init__(self, value: float, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(value = value * 1.618, **kwargs)

This functions as-desired at runtime…but now when I type FloatWM( Pylance shows only:
(*, value: float, **kwargs: Unknown) -> FloatWM
Is there a syntax or pattern I can use to get clean IntelliSense in VS Code for the subclass?
The Real Setup
To avoid an XY problem with my simplified code above:
The core use case is to have many different fields in many different classes, some of which wrap a pint.Quantity. Each field specifies the required dimensionality and base unit for that field. The dimensionality is enforced when constructing the value for the field, and the default units are applied if not supplied.
class ValueWithAttribution(BaseModel):
    value: Any
    source: str
    # more fields here

class NumberWithAttribution(ValueWithAttribution):
    value: float | int

type QuantityOrLiteral = float | int | str | PydanticPintQuantity

class QuantityWithAttribution(ValueWithAttribution):
    value: Quantity

    def __init__(self, value: QuantityOrLiteral, **kwargs):
        units = self.__class__.__annotations__.get("value").__metadata__[0].units
        if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
            super().__init__(value=Quantity(value, units), **kwargs)
        else:
            if isinstance(value, str):
                value = Quantity(value)
            if value.units.is_compatible_with(units):
                super().__init__(value=value, **kwargs)
            else:
                # raise hell
            
class Length(QuantityWithAttribution):
    value: Annotated[Quantity, PydanticPintQuantity("meters")]
    
class Weight(QuantityWithAttribution):
    value: Annotated[Quantity, PydanticPintQuantity("kg")]
    
class Person(MyBase):
    height: Length
    weight: Weight

me = Person(
    height = Length('70 inches', source='I said so'),
    weight = Weight(84, source='my treacherous scale')
) 


Outside the scope of this question, but related topic: if I want Pylance to accept the positional argument when constructing Length() and Weight(), I believe I also have to add this to each and every such leaf class (despite the fact that their parent class already has this signature):
class Length(QuantityWithAttribution):
    value: Annotated[Quantity, PydanticPintQuantity("meters")]

    # This is not functionally needed, by is required for
    # Pylance to accept that there's a positional argument :'(
    def __init__(self, value: QuantityOrLiteral, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(value=value, **kwargs)


The simplest solution is:
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class NumberWithMetadata(BaseModel):
    value: float | int
    source: str

class FloatWM(NumberWithMetadata):
    value: float = Field(kw_only=False)

    if not TYPE_CHECKING:
        def __init__(self, value: float | str, **kwargs):
            ...

The bigest drawback about this is, that you __init__ won't be type-checked at all like this...
